# Saving bool property to file in iOS.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I want save bool property to my file, and I did it in my opinion is barbaric. I have to check my property and then add string to NSMutableArray. Can I some how check property name, state/value and then save to file? Or maybe I should use XML file for this? But still for efficient use I should get property name and state/value.

Could you  give me some advice?

```
-(void) saveSettings
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@""];

    if (music)
    {
        [correctSettingArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [correctSettingArray addObject:@"music = 1"];
    }
    else
    {
        [correctSettingArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [correctSettingArray addObject:@"music = 0"];
    }

    if (sfx)
    {
        [correctSettingArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
        [correctSettingArray addObject:@"sfx = 1"];
    }
    else
    {
        [correctSettingArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [correctSettingArray addObject:@"sfx = 0"];
    }

    if (vibration)
    {
        [correctSettingArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [correctSettingArray addObject:@"vibration = 1"];
    }
    else
    {
        [correctSettingArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [correctSettingArray addObject:@"vibration = 0"];
    }

[correctSettingArray writeToFile:path atomically:true];

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to save simple application settings like this use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:vibrationBool forKey:@"vibrationKey"];
```

then when you want to read it

```
BOOL vibrationBool = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"vibrationKey"];
```

Comment: If the boolean value is optional, you need to check for its presence: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"] != nil)`. Shorthand method `boolForKey:` returns `NO` in case the parameter is not set.

Comment: Thanks, if I want restore that settings after terminatio the app, should I save those settins to DB/file or SDk will magically manage wit it?

Comment: NSUserDefaults are saved by the system at regular intervals, but if you are seeing times when the value returned is not correct after terminating the app, try calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after setting a value. This will persist the current values. You don't need to worry about writing these to disk yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save as NSNumber using this...

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:BOOLATR]
```

and retrieve the value doing...

```
BOOLATR = [[correctSettingArray objectAtIndex:X] boolValue]
```

In any case, you could prefer to use NSMutableDictionary for variable matching instead an array.

```
[dictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:BOOLATR] forKey:@"BOOLATR"];
```

&

```
BOOLATR = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"BOOLATR"] boolValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you ask — saving user settings — you should use `NSUserDefaults` as described in answer by *wattson12*.

If you really need to **save boolean properties to file**, given you are working with Objective-C objects, easiest way would be to use *archive* and serialize your data structure by implementing the `NSCoding` protocol. See Apple's [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/).

The `NSCoding` protocol has two parts: `initWithCoder` is basically another constructor for your object:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if ([decoder containsValueForKey:@"sunNeverSet"])
            self.sunNeverSet = [NSNumber numberWithBool:
              [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"sunNeverSet"]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The `encodeWithCoder` is the serialization:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (sunNeverRise) [coder encodeBool:[sunNeverRise boolValue] 
                                 forKey:@"sunNeverRise"];
}
```

Then you would encode your object graph into platform-independent byte stream (ie. `NSData`) using the `NSKeyedArchiver` and write the data to file.

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] 
                              initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

[archiver encodeRootObject:myObjectImplementingNSCoding];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

To read it back, you'll decode the data using `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and get back your object graph.

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] 
                                  initForReadingWithData:data];
id myObjectImplementingNSCoding = [[unarchiver decodeObject] retain];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```